Docker is utilizing 100% of the CPU on all cores of the host, yet `docker stats` indicates a usage of only 2%
I have a Debian 12 server with 2 CPU, 1.9 GB RAM, and Docker 24.0.6.
After a reboot, CPU usage is at 0%. Starting a Docker container, CPU usage spikes to 75-100% on all cores of the host.
Checking with docker stats, it shows 0-2% CPU usage for the container.
Even after stopping the container, Docker continues to utilize 75-100% of all cores, despite all containers being halted.
I tried:

Docker 24 running on Ubuntu 24.04:
Scanning for corrupt files:
sudo find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -name *-json.log -exec bash -c ‘jq ‘.’ {} > /dev/null 2>&1 || echo “file corrupt: {}”’ ; I deleted the files but keeps coming back.
system prune, rebuild images but comes back.
I tried a reinstall, same thing

How to solve this issue?
Details:
uname -a
Linux host 6.1.0-21-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.90-1 (2024-05-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1 40G 11G 27G 29% /

iotop
Total DISK READ: 0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE: 551.26 K/s
Current DISK READ: 0.00 B/s | Current DISK WRITE: 6.19 M/s
TID PRIO USER DISK READ DISK WRITE> COMMAND
1157386 be/4 root 0.00 B/s 195.38 K/s dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
716 be/4 root 0.00 B/s 188.41 K/s dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
706 be/4 root 0.00 B/s 167.47 K/s dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock



sudo docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version: 24.0.6
API version: 1.43
Go version: go1.20.7
Git commit: ed223bc
Built: Mon Sep 4 12:32:10 2023
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Context: default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version: 24.0.6
API version: 1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version: go1.20.7
Git commit: 1a79695
Built: Mon Sep 4 12:32:10 2023
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Experimental: false
containerd:
Version: 1.6.24
GitCommit: 61f9fd88f79f081d64d6fa3bb1a0dc71ec870523
runc:
Version: 1.1.9
GitCommit: v1.1.9-0-gccaecfc
docker-init:
Version: 0.19.0
GitCommit: de40ad0

docker stats
CONTAINER ID NAME CPU % MEM USAGE / LIMIT MEM % NET I/O BLOCK I/O PIDS
xyz abc 0.12% 402.7MiB / 1.89GiB 20.80% 1.34GB / 176MB 381MB / 22.6MB 21



docker info
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version: 24.0.6
Context: default
Debug Mode: false
Plugins:
buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
Version: v0.11.2
Path: /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
Version: v2.21.0
Path: /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
Containers: 2
Running: 1
Paused: 0
Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 24.0.6
Storage Driver: overlay2
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Supports d_type: true
Using metacopy: false
Native Overlay Diff: true
userxattr: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Cgroup Version: 2
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 61f9fd88f79f081d64d6fa3bb1a0dc71ec870523
runc version: v1.1.9-0-gccaecfc
init version: de40ad0
Security Options:
apparmor
seccomp
Profile: builtin
cgroupns
Kernel Version: 6.1.0-21-cloud-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.89GiB
Name: host
ID: xyz
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode: false
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

vmstat -S m 1 3 
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
17  1      0  28115   1167   1889    0    0    59  2907 26603 113599 30 45 24  1  0
15  0      0  28115   1167   1889    0    0     0 38399 371572 1357653 36 57  7  1  0
18  1      0  28115   1167   1889    0    0     0 39100 356942 1317990 37 54  8  1  0

[UPDATE] Following the @Timmy Browne advice, I did :
sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images -q)
sudo docker system prune
/var/lib/docker/containers# ls -thal
total 8.0K
drwx--x---  2 root root 4.0K May 25 13:51 .
drwx--x--- 12 root root 4.0K May 25 12:31 ..
/var/lib/docker/containers# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            957M     0  957M   0% /dev
tmpfs           194M  472K  194M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        40G  4.1G   34G  11% /
tmpfs           968M     0  968M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda15      124M   12M  113M  10% /boot/efi

After rebuilding the app :
sudo docker run -it 25dbde490595 &

The CPU is once again at 100%... After stopping the container :
sudo find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -name *-json.log -exec bash -c ‘jq ‘.’ {} > /dev/null 2>&1 || echo “file corrupt: {}”’ ;

No corrupted files found. Any idea of what's going on ?
[UPDATE 2]
sudo cat /proc/pressure/memory
some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0

find /sys/fs/cgroup -name memory.pressure | xargs grep . | sort -t= -k2n | tail -n10
grep: /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/system-serialx2dgetty.slice/serial-getty@ttyS1.service/memory.pressure: No such file or directory
grep: /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/system-serialx2dgetty.slice/memory.pressure: No such file or directory
grep: /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/dev-disk-byx2duuid-ddb6b1e4x2df7c1x2d4c6bx2d822cx2d6272d41983dd.swap/memory.pressure: No such file or directory
grep: /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/dev-disk-byx2duuid-8835e766x2d380fx2d4b84x2db612x2df69944a48800.swap/memory.pressure: No such file or directory
/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-3.scope/memory.pressure:full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-3.scope/memory.pressure:some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/dbus.socket/memory.pressure:full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/dbus.socket/memory.pressure:some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/memory.pressure:full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/memory.pressure:some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/init.scope/memory.pressure:full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/init.scope/memory.pressure:some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/memory.pressure:full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/memory.pressure:some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0

[UPDATE 3]
sudo apt install linux-perf
sudo perf record -a -F399 sleep 10
perf report


Samples: 47K of event 'cycles', Event count (approx.): 493082755290
Overhead  Command          Shared Object                           Symbol
   3.29%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa42011f0
   2.57%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa420010f
   2.13%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa4201220
   2.07%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa4201169
   1.53%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa3be0c58
   1.44%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa420009d
   1.40%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa4200220
   1.32%  dockerd          dockerd                                 [.] regexp.(*Regexp).tryBacktrack
   1.28%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa4040345
   1.08%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa42011e6
   1.06%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa36af5f8
   1.02%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa36de5ae
   0.85%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa4040a27
   0.82%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa42001a9
   0.81%  runc             [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa3fdb7c7
   0.72%  docker           docker                                  [.] os/signal.signal_recv
   0.58%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa3641a38
   0.44%  docker           docker                                  [.] runtime.procyield.abi0
   0.42%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa42000a0
   0.39%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa4200215
   0.38%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa40408c9
   0.37%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa3640871
   0.37%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa40404da
   0.35%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa37000c1
   0.35%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa36414b5
   0.33%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa4040393
   0.33%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa36e982d
   0.30%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa36d3b7d
   0.30%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa4040893
   0.29%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa4040711
   0.28%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa36afdb8
   0.28%  docker           docker                                  [.] runtime.sigsend
   0.25%  docker           docker                                  [.] runtime.mapiternext
   0.24%  docker           docker                                  [.] runtime.futex.abi0
   0.24%  docker           [kernel.kallsyms]                       [k] 0xffffffffa36e349e
   0.24%  docker           docker                                  [.] runtime/internal/syscall.Syscall6

[UPDATE 4]
It seems that's related to python asyncio used inside the container. I have some code to reproduce the issue
import asyncio
import logging
import time

# Define the logger
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Async function to run indefinitely
async def main():
    try:
        while True:
            #if should_end():
            #    break
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
            logger.info("Ping")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        logger.info("Program interrupted by user (source: CancelledError).")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logger.info("Program interrupted by user (source: KeyboardInterrupt).")

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11.7
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app
CMD [ "python3", "./asyncio_test.py" ]

I'm not alone expericing issue with asyncio.sleep and docker :

Python service uses 100% of CPU on while loop with sleep (inside docker container)

[UPDATE 5]





What is the result of command vmstat 1 3?

Add this in question and format it properly

check your log file directory. clean it up. check your disk space.   validate the logs aren't corrupt.

The high sys% and wait% in the vmstat output suggests paging pressure. What is the output of /proc/pressure/memory and find /sys/fs/cgroup -name memory.pressure | xargs grep . | sort -t= -k2n | tail -n10

No paging so I'd now consider running perf record -a -F399 sleep 10 and then running perf report and providing the results.

If docker is written in go, how do you explain this as being python asyncio? Your perf results are missing a great deal of kernel symbols -- may be a distro oddity I'm not aware of. However it looks like theres a great deal of chatter between threads being used in docker so they wake up a lot. Its possible (although I imagine unlikely) strace might show whats going on. Or, just check the main dockerd logs and see what its doing. Up the loglevel and restart if not.

I clarified the update 4. It's python used inside the container.

Try profiling the python in something like py-spy in that case. You can attach to the running process with it.

This doesn't appear to be anything to do with python from the py-spy results. Looks like a docker anomaly.

I completely agree. After few days, containers are frozen and I need to restart the host. The good question is : how to solve this issue :)

Apparently the CPU usage is not from the container (neither the "shim" nor anything that runs inside a container), but the docker client process. (I'm not saying that what runs inside the containers are irrelevant though.) Have you tested whether --detach makes a difference?

@Tom Yan found the solution :
Instead of running the image using :
docker run -it [container_id] &

If I use
docker run -d [container_id]

I get a normal CPU usage.

This does sound like a bug in the docker client though. Out of curiosity, does the problem occur again if you docker attach the container? And does it go away again if you then detach from it (with the key sequence CTRL-p CTRL-q)?

I did sudo docker attach 5bb48cbe544d, does no make any difference
